# Oneliner to extract External IP from IFCONFIG.CO

Tags: powershell

I wrote a small function in powershell that works fine, however I feel its extremely hacky and I'm sure there must be a smarter way to do this. In the interests of learning, what can I do to improve on this?

```
function WhatsMyIP
{
return ((Invoke-RestMethod -Uri http://ifconfig.co).split("`n") | where {$_ -match "`"ip`""}).split("<").split(">")[4]
}
```

I tried this with `Invoke-WebRequest` but the returned data is the same, except you need to expand the `.content` property to get at it, making this slightly *more* clunky than before.

I'd like to do this natively, I realise I can just invoke CURL or what ever but the point is that I am very likely to be on systems where CURL isn't available when I need this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the **easiest way** to get **Public/External IP** from **ifconfig.co** using **CMD** or **Powershell** is:

**In Powershell:**

```
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri http://ifconfig.co -UserAgent "curl"
```

**in CMD:**

```
powershell Invoke-RestMethod -Uri http://ifconfig.co -UserAgent "curl"
```

**In a BATCH (.bat/.cmd) file:**

```
@echo off
for /f "usebackq" %%i in (`powershell -Command Invoke-RestMethod -Uri http://ifconfig.co -UserAgent "curl"`) do set IP=%%i
echo My ip is: %IP%
```

Results:

[image: cmd results from powershell Invoke-RestMethod -Uri http://ifconfig.co]

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! You have presented an alternative solution, but haven't reviewed the code. Please [edit] it to explain your reasoning (how your solution works and how it improves upon the original) so that everyone can learn from your thought process.

Answer (score 4):

I don't like the idea of using `Invoke-RestMethod` here. Normally it would return an object, but here it just returns html as a string, which isn't much use to us. I guess that's because the payload is not XML or JSON, so PowerShell can't turn it into an object for us.

`Invoke-WebRequest` in contrast will parse the HTML for us, and then we can filter out the element we want:

```
function WhatsMyIP
{
    $x = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri http://ifconfig.co
    $elt = $x.AllElements | ? { $_.tagName -eq 'CODE' -and $_.class -eq 'ip' }
    $elt.innerText
}
```

The question mark `?` means "where". (It's an alias for `Where-Object`.) So, what we are doing is we get all the HTML elements on the page, and we filter out all of them except the ones that have a tagName of 'CODE' and a class of 'ip'. (There will only be one of them on this particular page.) We are catching this element: `<code class="ip">1.2.3.4</code>`.

That's "screen scraping" though, which is a bit crappy. I notice on the web site that they provide JSON if you give them the right URL. Now we can use `Invoke-RestMethod`:

```
function WhatsMyIP
{
    $x = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri ifconfig.co/all.json
    $x.'X-Real-Ip'
}
```

Note that there's no need to use `return`. Any unconsumed objects will be put in the pipeline. If you don't understand the pipeline, you should read up on it, because it is key to understanding PowerShell.

Comment: Thanks for this, your second example makes sense and works for me but your first does not. 

Breaking it down $x.allelements returns as expected, when I append the piped commands nothing is returned. I admit I don't really understand the function of the ? nor do i understand the purpose of the $tagname variable you call within the script block. Do you mind expanding on these?

Comment: @Patrick, sorry about that, there was a typo. I have fixed it now. (I don't know how that happened. I do test, and I always copy-and-paste.) I will add some explanatory text above about the question mark.

Comment: Thank you for this. I can't believe I hadn't grasped the concept that ? (or indeed %) after a pipe was simply an alias. Mindblown.gif. Thank you for your answer, I really appreciate the time and thought.